# Getting 404 from Postman PATCH request

Tags: sqlite, postman, knex.js

I have the get routing `router.get('/users', getAllUsers)` which calls

```
export const getAllUsers: RequestHandler = (req, res, next) => {
  knex
  .select(
    'Users.UserID',
    'Users.FirstName',
    'FaceRecognition.FaceFeature'
  )
  .from('Users')
  .leftJoin('FaceRecognition', 'Users.FaceID', 'FaceRecognition.FaceID')
  .then((result: User) => {
    res.json(result)
  })
};
```

returning

```
[
    {
        "UserID": 2,
        "FirstName": "Minor",
        "FaceFeature": 23.2
    },
    {
        "UserID": 1,
        "FirstName": "Major",
        "FaceFeature": 19.9
    }
]
```

as it should. My patch routing `router.patch('./editUser', editUser);` however
is supposed to call this knex routine:

```
export const editUser: RequestHandler = (req, res, next) => {
  const {UserID, FirstName, FaceFeature} = req.body;
  knex('Users')
  .where('UserID', '=', UserID)
  .update({
    FirstName: FirstName
  })
  .then(() => {
    res.status(204).end()
  })
};
```

Using Postman I send a PATCH request to `localhost:8080/admin/editUser` with the JSON request body

```
{
    "UserID": 2, 
    "FirstName": "Patcher", 
    "FaceFeature": 1
}
```

I just get a `404 not found` and `Cannot PATCH /admin/editUser`. Any clues to why?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the routing url `'./editUser'` to `'/editUser'`. Embarrassing dev error, hopefully the answer can lead someone else out of debugging fog.